# PC doesn't turn on - no noise or lights

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

I just tried to start my PC but it didn't. No lights and no fans running. Then I pressed once more the start button and something blew - I guess the power supply but I'm not sure.

Any ideas of what can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the power supply by ["jump starting"](http://www.bleedinedge.com/forum/showthread.php?29759-Jump-Starting-ATX-Power-Supplies) it. I recommend to unplug all internal components (mainboard, HDD, CD/DVD, ...) before trying that. If the power supply fan(s) start spinning, it is likely that it still works and the fault might be with your mainboard or another component.

Comment: No, the fan is not spinning. Which means 100% that the PSU is gone?

Comment: I would say 90%, fairly certain but unless you also test the voltages, you can't tell 100%. A new PSU is cheap and should give you 100% clarity ;)

Comment: Also no lights and noise with a new PSU

Answer (score 1):

Just plug your power cable out and wait for 5 minutes and try again.
If it does not work again, check all the cables attached to your computer.
If still not, i would suggest that you will bring your computer to a Computer repair technician.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: No lights at all? Check the inside cables also maybe the power cable just pop out from the motherboard

Comment: Nothing. All inside cables are OK.